# Tooltip is cutting off from parent

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, frontend

My tooltip is cutting off from the parent and the parent has `overflow: auto;` property. If I remove that property, the tooltip is displays overflow from the parent which is fine, but when I add that property, the tooltip is cutting off. Please provide me the best solution for that.

[image]

```
.tooltip{
    back ground: #303030;
    color: #b4b4b4;
    padding: 0.5em 1em;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    display: none;
    margin-bottom: 0.75em;
    animation: shortcut-tooltip-open 200ms ease-out;
    transform-origin: 50% 100%;
    white-space: nowrap;
    z-index: 1002;
    border-radius: 2px;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-transform: none;
}



<div class="main overflow-x-auto">
   <div class="item position-relative">
      <span class="show-tooltip-on-hover">Show tooltip</span>
      <div class="tooltip">
        // some text or list
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what's the html for the tooltip? Can you create an example where we see the cut off tooltip?

Comment: @cloned I've attached the screenshot.

Answer (score -2):

```
enter code here
```

parent is-class="item position-relative"
child is - class="tooltip"

try these
`* {box-sizing: border-box;}` 
`.item position-relative{width:200px;/* use as per your req.*/}` 
`.tooltip{width:100%;}`